# How to include application version number in HTML documentation genertated by Spring Rest Docs?

Tags: spring-restdocs

I would like to include application version number (`version` from `build.gradle`).

I see no way to pass some custom variables to ascidoc and use them in generated documentation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing custom variables from gradle can be done using

```
 asciidoctor {   
    attributes "build=${build}" 
  }
```

Then defined attribute may be refered in `adoc` file as  `{build}`

Comment: Exactly, Gradle documentation: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/#options-attributes Maven documentation: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/#passing-pom-properties Some attributes like `project.version` are even passed automatically.